# Accessing arrays in different menu

Tags: java

I have a menu with 3 options. Option 1 is add student record. I'm adding this using:

```
public String getName()
{
return name;
}
public void setName(String a)
{
name=a; 
}
```

Then after the user input I will ask if he wants to input again. Else my code is `myclass.main(null)` to go back to my main menu. And the menu will pop up again with 3 choices.

The 2nd option is to search the added record. The problem is that I don't know how can I access this. What array must I declare to access it again?

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: this is my array in adding students rec[] mskt=new rec[10];

Comment: then i dont know what array should i use in my next option to access that

Comment: use an enhanced for loop, like that: `for (rec student : mskt) { ... }` and inside the loop, check for equality, e.g., by name, like that : `if (userInput.equals(student.getName())) { ... }`

Comment: im trying to use this ch==mskt[a].getId() but no for loop ? maybe ill watch youtube for using the enhanced for loop ?

Comment: ijust dont know how can i access the arrays from my opt 1 to my opt 2 ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, define a `Student` class (I think that you call it `rec`), which will contain all the information that you need to keep about a student, such as the name, id, etc.

Then, in your main method, create an array, or better an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of Students (since you do not know in advance how many `Student` instances the user will create).

It's as easy as:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, each time the user chooses to add a new student (Option 1), create a `Student` instance like that:

```
Student student = new Student();
```

and then set its name, id, etc, by calling:

```
student.setName(userInput);
```

where `userInput` is the String variable with a value that the user gave.

After that, add the new `Student` instance to the ArrayList, by calling:

```
students.add(student);
```

Finally, you can iterate over the students list, by using a simple for loop:

```
for (Student student : students) {
    if (student.getId() == usersQueryId){
        //the student that the user is looking for was found!
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, define a `boolean equals(Student other)` method inside the Student class, to define the way that you wish to check Students for equality.

Comment: sir the user will input name then student ID .. i want to use the student ID as the search .. but im really new in arrays .. but i will try this  even tho i dont know where to start

Comment: @JoshuaGonzales I have updated my answer, accordingly, assuming that id  is an int variable defined in the Student class. Start step by step, by building the Student class first, and then checking that each step that you do is working properly (using some test students). Do not wait until you build the whole code to test it all afterwards...